# How can I calculate how much weight can lift my stepper motor?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, structural-engineering

I have this stepper motor: [Stepper Motor, Nema 17 Stepper Motor 4-lead 1.8 Deg 40N.cm Holding Torque 1.7A 42 Motor with Motor Mounting Bracket and Screws for 3D Printer/CNC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B071LTXQGW)

I want to know how can I calculate how much weight it motor can lift in this situation:

[image]

Comment: We’d have to know the specifications of the lead screw.